# Search and replace occurrences of pattern with sequential variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have a requirement to update a variable across multiple files/sub-directories. The variable to be replaced starts with the same 6 characters, everything after this is random. I will use these first 6 characters as the pattern to find/replace on. I will replace the random characters following with a sequential variable.

I'm not sure what utility is best to achieve this but I imagine sed in some kind of loop? I'm struggling to visualise how best to achieve this. I imagine it could be done with something like;

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  
i=0  
grep -r '/parent/sub/' -e 'pattern' | while read line  
do  
sed 's/pattern*/pattern$i/g'  
((i++))  
done
```

My first issue is I don't know if sed can be used this way, secondly as it's nested in the loop how do can I feed it the required lines from the grep command (or is there a better method than grep to be used here?)

Thanks

Comment: I think the first thing you would need to identify is how deeply nested your directory structure is. Everything else can probably be done with `sed` or `awk` - however, note that the search pattern you indicated is that of "wildcards" ([globs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) in the shell language), whereas for `sed` you will need a ["regular expression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Also, be careful that in your example, you would be replacing the pattern with literal `$i` as variable expansion is disabled inside single quotes.

Comment: yes, please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input files, the output you would desire from that file. How do you decide where the "random characters" end? Can the pattern be found more than once on the same line? More than once in the same file?

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` in that context as it's ambiguous, always use `string` or `regexp`, whichever one you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0 
grep -rl --exclude=${0:2} . -e pattern | while read -r line               
do                                                
    sed -i 's/pattern\(.*\)/pattern'$i'/' "$line"    
    ((i++))                                           
done
```

The `while` loop cycles over all filenames in the current directory (and recursively on subfolders) containing an instance of "pattern".
Using `sed`, you replace everything that follows 'pattern' in that line, indicated by the group `\(.*\)`, by 'pattern' and the value of the counter `i`.

---

Notes:

- This works also if you have many 'pattern' strings in different lines, but would not work if you have multiple 'pattern' strings in the same line, since everything that follows 'pattern' would be replaced.
- `sed -i` replace the files inplace, if you just want to check if it replace everything correctly, remove `-i`.
- I added the option `--exclude=${0:2}` in the `grep` call, since if you search in the current directory without it, it will match also the script filename, since it contains the strings 'pattern'!!

Comment: Please note that your approach may suffer from the same problem that leads to the discouragement of [parsing the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), in that the loop may choke on filenames with special characters (or even spaces, which are not so uncommon anymore) - `grep` doesn't have the equivalent of the `-print0` option that GNU `find` has, as far as I remember ...

Comment: You are right, I missed the whitespace management, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this Giuseppe, I've marked this as the answer as after initial testing it's definitely on the right path for what I'm attempting to achieve.

Comment: You are welcome! I noticed a funny loophole however. If you search the pattern in the current directory `.`, in the loop would be also the script, so it replace everything after 'pattern'!! If you use something like the above as commands in the shell it will work, but using that as a script would be a problem. I'm tring to figure out how to manage that.

Comment: Ok, fixed that.

Comment: That would strip leading/trailing white space from every file name, if you're going to use a while-read loop you should always use `while IFS= read -r` unless you have a specific reason not to set `IFS=` or not to use `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

The tool to **find** files is named `find`, not `grep`. There is a big clue in the name of the tool :-). `grep` is to **G**lobally find a **R**egular **E**xpression within a file/stream and **P**rint the result - it's the letters from the `ed` command `g/re/p`. The GNU guys really messed up by giving `grep` options to find files - hopefully they don't have any plans to have it take on the functions of sort, tr, sed, wc, etc. next!

Here's one way to do what you want robustly (making assumptions about when you want i incremented, what you mean by pattern, which characters pattern can contain, etc.):

```
i=0
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    grep -q 'pattern' "$file" &&
    sed -i 's/pattern*/pattern'"$i"'/g' "$file"
    ((i++))
done < <(find '/parent/sub/' -type f -print0)
```